# Weak keyword with computed properties

Tags: swift

```
private weak var _delegate: SomeClassDelegate?
weak var delegate: SomeClassDelegate? {
    get {
        return _delegate
    }
    set {
        _delegate = newValue
    }
}
```

This is valid code. Is there is any sense in using `weak` keyword with computed `delegate` property? Logically no; how compiler will process through this code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there is any sense in using `weak` keyword with computed delegate property?

Not only is it sensible to do so, but it’s important to do so. This computed property is your public interface to this private hidden property. If the computed property lacks the `weak` qualifier, callers will draw incorrect conclusions about the underlying semantics.

Consider:

```
class SomeClass {
    private weak var _delegate: SomeClassDelegate?
    var delegate: SomeClassDelegate? {             // whoops; this should be `weak`
        get { return _delegate }
        set { _delegate = newValue }
    }
}
```

And

```
class CustomDelegate: SomeClassDelegate { ... }
```

Then

```
let object = SomeClass()
object.delegate = CustomDelegate()
```

In the absence of the the `weak` qualifier on the computed property and without diving into the implementation details, the programmer might incorrectly conclude that the above is fine. But it’s not. Because the underlying `_delegate` is `weak`, this `CustomDelegate()` instance will be deallocated immediately, and the object will end up with no delegate object. And there’s no compiler warning about this behavior.

If, however, we fix `SomeClass` like so:

```
class SomeClass {
    private weak var _delegate: SomeClassDelegate?
    weak var delegate: SomeClassDelegate? {        // great; matches underlying semantics
        get { return _delegate }
        set { _delegate = newValue }
    }
}
```

Then the programmer will receive a very helpful warning:

```
let object = SomeClass()
object.delegate = CustomDelegate()  // results in "Instance will be immediately deallocated because property 'delegate' is 'weak'"
```

They’ll then correctly deduce that they should keep their own strong reference to this `CustomDelegate` for the code to work properly.

So, bottom line, you don’t technically need the `weak` qualifier on the computed property that is backed by a private `weak` stored property, but it’s prudent to do so to avoid mysterious bugs and/or misunderstandings about the underlying semantics.

Comment: Just a word of caution, if any one is using SwiftLint there s a default enabled rule [`weak_computed_property`](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/blob/master/Rules.md#weak-computed-property) which would keep deleting the `weak` reference, if you need the compiler warnings just disable it for that line.

Comment: @GoodSp33d - Thanks for pointing that out. I’ve now added it to my list of disabled rules in my `.swiftlint.yml` and have [suggested they revisit this rule](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/issues/2596).

Comment: They have removed this `weak_computed_property` rule. See [#2712](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/issues/2712), removed in [#2761](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/pull/2761).

Answer (score 2):

Computed properties aren't retain by ARC, so you don't need to mark it as weak.

Only one pros that I know about is to ensure that property could be nil in future. You **cannot** declare it as:

```
weak var youProperty: YourType { 
    get {
        return _yourProperty
    } 
    set { 
        _yourProperty = newValue
    }
}
```